# Flutter FormBuilderTextField remove autocorrection and other formatters

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have `FormBuilderTextField`, where user provide his login.

```dart
                FormBuilderTextField(
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  name: 'login',
                  validator: FormBuilderValidators.required(),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Login'),
                ),
```

But keyboard force first letter as Capital, and moreover add space after write one word. How to block this features? I need exatly same phrase like user fill in form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting as follows:

```
FormBuilderTextField(
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none, // Added
  autocorrect: false, // Added
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  name: 'login',
  validator: FormBuilderValidators.required(),
  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Login'),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `autocorrect : false` as showing below :

```
    FormBuilderTextField(
                  autocorrect : false
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  name: 'login',
                  validator: FormBuilderValidators.required(),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Login'),
                ),
```